# codeIgniter send mail with attechment not work

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$path=$this->email->config->item('server_root');
$file=$path.'/mail_demo/attechment/mytext.txt';
```

my mail is not sent,i don't know what wrong there is generate following error
Undefined property: `CI_Email::$config`

Comment: hay  solve this just change following  $path=$this->config->item('server_root');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->email->attach('/mail_demo/attechment/mytext.txt');
```

Use CodeIgnigters email class.